# Spring boot service inside docker PKIX path building failed:SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ssl

I have created a nodejs service (target server) which is using self-signed certificate which was generated using below command.

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365`

In another service implemeted using spring boot, which is running in docker container with base image as `openjdk:11` and it tries to connect to above target server.

I have added the self-signed certificate in container JDK's default truststore

i.e. `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security` using below command.

`keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass <default_password_here> -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias <custom_alias_name> -file cert.pem`

Verified that above certificate is added into keystore using below command.

`keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts`

But in spring boot service getting an exception as below:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341) ~[na:na]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

Not able to find the problem, please help.